# Rails - Simple Form Bootstrap - show full text of error inline - (or anywhere)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, simple-form, nested-forms

I am struggling to  figure out how to use simple form with rails 5 so that I can show full error messages in my forms. All I get is a box at the top with a message that says:

```
Please review the problems below:
```

Instead of a list of problems or any highlighted form fields - i don't get anything.

I  have followed the  advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358068/show-full-error-messages-with-simple-form) and replaced all references to error in my initialiser with 'full_error', but that only solves the problem for the parent form - nested fields still just get an incomplete error message. Does anyone know how to identify errors in simple form?

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-danger'
  config.button_class = 'btn btn-green'
  config.boolean_label_class = nil

  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

    b.use :input
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input
    end

    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
    b.use :input
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
      ba.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9' do |wr|
      wr.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |ba|
        ba.use :label_input
      end

      wr.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      wr.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :inline_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'sr-only'

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :multi_select, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'form-inline' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
      ba.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end
  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :vertical_form
  config.wrapper_mappings = {
    check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :vertical_file_input,
    boolean: :vertical_boolean,
    datetime: :multi_select,
    date: :multi_select,
    time: :multi_select
  }
end
```

**FORM**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@proposal) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

 <% @proposal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= li= msg %>
 <% end %>



  <div class="form-inputs" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
  <!--   General Organisation details -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :title, :label => "Title" %>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :byline, :label => "Tagline" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text, :label => "Outline your proposal", input_html: { rows: 15 } %>
      </div>
    </div>




  <!--   Package: :ethics considerations -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form_title">Research Ethics</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= render 'package/ethics/ethics_fields', f: f %>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another ethics issue', f, :ethics, partial: 'package/ethics/ethics_fields' %>
    </div>
  </div>


  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="margin-top: 50px">
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**NESTED FIELDS**

```
<div class="nested-fields">

    <%# @proposal.ethics.errors.full_messages.each do |e| %>
        <li><%#=  e  %></li>
    <%# end %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 ">
          <%= f.select :category, [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], { label: "Principle" }, id: "main_category" %>
          <%= f.select :subcategory, [], {}, id: "sub_category", disabled: true %>
          <%= f.input :consideration, as: :text, :label => "Identify the ethics considerations?",  :input_html => {:rows => 8} %>
          <%= f.input :plan, as: :text, :label => "How will these considerations be managed?",  :input_html => {:rows => 8} %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 50px">
        <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove this ethical issue', f %>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting haml and erb mixed up in your error displaying code.

This:

```
 <% @proposal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   <%= li= msg %>
 <% end %>
```

should look more like this:

```
<% if @proposal.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @proposal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I'm guessing you are using Cocoon so you'll need to set that up correctly but there is a gotcha when using Rails 5.

You'll need something like the following in your models:

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: :ethics, inverse_of: :proposal
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ethics ...
...
```

and

```
class Ethic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :proposal, inverse_of: :ethics
...
```

note the has_many .. inverse_of clause which works round a bug in Rails 5.

If you setup the accepts_nested_attributes_for clause correctly I think @proposal.errors should contain all the errors for the form.

Comment: You're right with the inverse thing on the ethic model - that made the error go away, but how do i print the errors for the ethic attributes in the nested part of the ethics form? They list at the top of the form, with the proposal list of errors, but all i get when I scroll down to the ethics attributes is a red box saying please review the issues below, and then no list.

Comment: I don't think there is an obvious way to split the parent and child errors.  I'd remove the "<%= f.error_notification %>" line from the simple_fields_for block and rely on simple_form to produce your error messages.  BTW as Sravan said you do need a different variable for your simple_fields_for block.

Comment: but it actually works fine with the f :f - i'm not sure that I do  need it. The attributes are being created using f (the same as proposal).

Comment: Just note that the f within the simple_fields_for block is a different (local) variable to the f within the simple_form_for block.  Changing it's name makes that obvious and may help in the future if you (or someone else) need to revisit this form.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake I found in your code is, in your nested field you have taken the same variable `f` in the parameter, which may get consfused with the parent parame`enter code here`ter `f`

So,

nested will be,

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.error_notification %>
      <%= render 'package/ethics/ethics_fields', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Now the form,

```
<%= simple_form_for(@proposal) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

 <% @proposal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= li= msg %>
 <% end %>



  <div class="form-inputs" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
  <!--   General Organisation details -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :title, :label => "Title" %>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :byline, :label => "Tagline" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text, :label => "Outline your proposal", input_html: { rows: 15 } %>
      </div>
    </div>




  <!--   Package: :ethics considerations -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form_title">Research Ethics</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.error_notification %>
        <%= render 'package/ethics/ethics_fields', f: ff %>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another ethics issue', f, :ethics, partial: 'package/ethics/ethics_fields' %>
    </div>
  </div>


  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="margin-top: 50px">
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>




<%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.error_notification %>
    <%= render 'package/ethics/ethics_fields', f: ff %>
    <% @proposal.ethics.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= li= msg %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: Even if the above does not solve the issue,

Try getting the errors from the `ethics object` from the `@proposal` variable

So,

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.error_notification %>
    <% @proposal.ethics.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= li= msg %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'package/ethics/ethics_fields', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: pls, check this answer, feel free to ask any queries.

Comment: but if that were the case, all of the ethics fields wouldn't work. f.input works fine in the ethics nested fields partial for the input elements. I cant find a way to display the errors in that form

Comment: The ethics fields mat work, but the error messages may not get displayed. check the last portion of the answer.

Comment: just print out `@proposal.errors` in the view and check if it has ethics object in it

Comment: it does. but i cant make the errors print in the the form.

Comment: let us try, what are you getting in `@proposal.errors`

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to display the error messages directly at the field.

```
<%= f.input :title, :label => "Title", id:"title" %>
<%= f.error :title, :id => "title_error" %>
```

This will show the error message for title next to the title field. You can add an f.error method to each field in your form instead of displaying a `<ul>` above the form, or together with a `<ul>` above your form.

For nested_form_fields try to add `validates_associated :assoc_model_name` into the main model. This will run validations for the associated model as well.

Comment: This should be happening automatically using the simple_form gem.  It includes the errors when needed even for the associated fields.

Answer (score 0):

to get it working inline with simple form by default you have to use bootstrap_simple-form and make sure everything within controller is set up correctly.

For reference check the answers given here by me and Hollownest

[Showing fields with errors for nested forms in Rails 3.2 + SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978473/showing-fields-with-errors-for-nested-forms-in-rails-3-2-simpleform/69553713#69553713)